# Dynamic method invocation in Groovy

Tags: dynamic, methods, groovy

I want to call **method1** or **method2** on *method* based on parameter code is it null or not

```
void add(def code, def index) {
    method(index).((code != null) ? "method1"(code) : "method2"())
}
```

But nothing happens? Where is my wrong? 
If I write

```
method(index)."method1"(code)
```

works but can not make the ternary operator works.

Comment: Could you provide a runnable example?

Comment: why so complicated? why not standard `expr ? method.method1(code) : method.method2()`?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov that will be based on groovy truth, not null

Comment: @tim_yates I mean why call it dynamically/parse method name from a string, if we already know it, on compile time, and can just call it as is, just as we do in plain java (`expr` is `code != null`)

Comment: @IgorArtamonov ahhh, `(code != null) ? method.method1(code) : method.method2()` sorry, thought you just meant the middle bit ;-)

Comment: yeah, i was just lazy here, sorry :)

Comment: @tim_yates but if I want to do it in this way / Where is my wrong? Because the name of method is over 20 letters and I want to make it shorter. I do not want to repeat method.....

Comment: @Xelian maybe if you could put an actual working example in the question that shows the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
void add(def code, def index) {
    method(index).with { m ->
        (code != null) ? m."method1"(code) : m."method2"()
    }
}
```

Or (as @IgorArtamonov points out in the comments above):

```
void add(def code, def index) {
    (code != null) ? method(index)."method1"(code) : method(index)."method2"()
}
```

Comment: Because it calls the method in the ternary, then tries to get the property returned by the method from the original `method(index)` returned object